# Create a shopify buy now for a product with a specific sku

Tags: shopify

How do I create a Shopify buy now button, if the only thing I know about the product, is the product name, variant name and sku?

And the sku is unique in our entire system.

Answer (score 0):

There's a sales channel for buy buttons now. If you can access the shop admin you can make a buy button for any product https://docs.shopify.com/manual/more/buy-button/create-buy-button#create-buy-button

Comment: Yes, but I don't need a buy button for a specific known product. 

I need to at runtime make a buy button which matches a specific product(using the products sku), without having to pre-generate 500 buy buttons. The system which need to show the buy button don't really know anything about products in Shopify. It just need to insert a buy button which matches the product in Shopify and which will open Shopify when clicked.